# Open Source Excel Engine

Tags: java, excel, open-source

I am looking for an Open Source Excel Engine which can run excel on the server and return the values back for the specified cells(support Excel Functions).

I am evaluating the following solutions, but don't have deep understanding  of whether they are good or bad solutions

- [OpenXLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxls/)
- [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/)

Another non-opensource solution I am also looking into is [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/).

If any body has experience with these tools or know any open source tools that can be used to process and run Excel files server side, please post your comments here.

Comment: Why mix Excel and a server? Why not just use a database?

Answer (score 1):

Andy Khan's JExcel is terrific, but I'm not sure if it supports Excel macros.  It's a great Excel API in every other respect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) can process Excel .xls files without the need for MS Excel installed. It can also process formulae, as shown [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html).